# How to use character string?

Tags: arrays, c, string

How to use character string?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

int main() {
    char string[] = { 'A+','A'};

    printf("%s", &string[0]);
    printf("%s", &string[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Hope to get help and reply from here.

Comment: to delimit a string use *double quotes* ... `"Hi"`, `"A"`, `""` <= empty string, .... Use apostrophe to delimit characters (or, kinda off limits, *multibyte characters*): `'X'`, `'\n'`, `'\0'` <= NUL character. A string is simply an array of plain `char` of which one element is the `'\0'`. Your array of char in the example has 2 elements, none of which is the `'\0'` so it is not a string. The `'A+'` *multibyte character* is kinda off limits.

Comment: In C language, a `char` object is a single character. Strings are not first class elements of the language, but are just *null terminated char arrays*. So this 2 declarations are strictly equivalent: `char s[] = "abc";` and `char s[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};`. Both declare an array of 4 characters...

Comment: @pmg -- "multibyte character is kinda off limits"  -- mean to say, multibyte characters are taboo on Stk Ovflw?  Pls say before I make the mistake of posting same someday.

Comment: @Kz2023 I meant "they're **kinda** off limits to **beginners**"... they're ok to discuss in StackOverflow.

Comment: @Adrian Ng, `char string[] = { 'A+','A'};` --> `char string[] = "A+A";`.  What results do you get?  What was desired?

Answer (score 2):

The line `char string[] = { 'A+','A'};` should not compile because 'A+' is not a valid character. Like pmg said, you should use double-quotation marks for strings eg`char sz[] = "A+B";`

The compiler should accept code like...

```
char string[] = { 'A', '+', 'B'};
puts(string);
```

... but you wouldn't want to run that code. It would end with a buffer overrun and likely memory access violation. It's better to use double quotes like in the first paragraph.

You could also declare an array of strings like:

```
char ppsz[][] = {"A+", "B"};
puts(ppsz[0]); /* prints A+ */
puts(ppsz[1]); /* prints B */
```

Comment: *"should not compile because 'A+' is not a valid character."* Unfortunately C standard allows integer character constants to have more than one character. Result is an implementation defined value, and not a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

Updated your string, pls try now.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    /* Fixed up -- added terminating NUL (\0), etc*/
    char string[] = { 'A','+','A','\0'};

    printf("%s", &string[0]);
    printf("%s", &string[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Runnable version at [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/c6GW1GTfK)

Comment: `&string[0]` and `&string[1]` mess with my brain! I prefer the equivalent `string` and `string + 1` respectively :)